# Apply sorting on date field of Elasticsearch in python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to get search result from Elasticsearch in **descending order of date in python**. For that I tried following -

```
conn = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
res = conn.search(
                    index = 'myData',
                    body = {
                        'query':{
                            "match_all":{}
                        },
                        "sort": [
                                {
                                    "date":{"order": "desc"}
                                }
                             ]
                    }
                    
                    
                )
print(res)
```

But above code is not working. Can anyone help me? Thanx in advance.

Comment: What data type is your `date` field?

Comment: What does "code is not working" mean? Do you get an error or not the expected results? Can you shed some light on that?

Comment: @Tomalak data type of date field is "date"

Comment: @Val I am not getting any error but not getting expected result as well

Comment: What results are you getting vs what are you expecting?

Comment: @val I am expecting that record with recent date should come first

Comment: @Val I am getting nothing, absolutely nothing

Comment: What happens when you execute the same query in Kibana Dev Tools?